# union inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, printf, scanf, unions

So, I have this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct lista{ 
    union info{
       double operando;
       char operador;
    }info;
 };

 typedef struct lista Lista;

 int main(){

 printf("char: ");
 scanf("%c", Lista.info.operador);
 getchar();
 printf("%c\n", Lista.info.operador);
 printf("double: ");
 scanf("%lf", Lista.info.operando);
 getchar();
 printf("%lf\n", Lista.info.operando);

 return 0;

 }
```

When i try to compile it, i get this error:

> error: expected expression before 'Lista'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On any particular line?

Comment: On all lines that appears: 'Lista.info.operando' or 'Lista.info.operador'

Comment: The main problem is you define a structure and then a type called Lista but you don't actually create an object of that type in main.  You need to work on an instance of your structure. So add something like `Lista myLista;` in main and the in main change all references of `Lista` to `myLista` . `myLista` is a variable name so it can be a name of your choosing.

Comment: One other consideration is that you aren't using scanf correctly. You need to pass the address of a character variable (or double) rather than an actual character or double. So you should be doing `scanf("%c", &Lista.info.operador);` and `scanf("%lf", &myLista.info.operando);` . On a side note `%lf` is a gcc format extension and isn't considered portable.

Comment: Now was only missing the &. Thanks!!!

Comment: My comment about `%lf` only applies if you are using C89 or C90 C standard. If your compiling as C99 `%lf` is a non issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lista` is a *type,* not a variable, you need to do something like:

```
Lista xyzzy;
:
scanf ("%c", &(xyzzy.info.operador));
```

You'll also notice that, because the `scanf` family of functions expect to be given *addresses* of variables so they can be populated, I've changed the call to use `&(xyzzy.info.operador)` instead of just `xyzzy.info.operador`.

---

And, unless you need to *use* the structure name, I tend to prefer defining the type name only, with something like:

```
typedef struct { 
    union {
        double operando;
        char operador;
    } info;
} Lista;
```

Comment: Now, I only get 2 warnings: /home/rafael-linux/Documents/ED/union/main.c||In function ‘main’:|
/home/rafael-linux/Documents/ED/union/main.c|16|warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]|
/home/rafael-linux/Documents/ED/union/main.c|20|warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: And a segmentation fault

Comment: @Rafael, that's because you're not passing the addresses of the variables. See my update.

Comment: @RafaelDias Something else that you will find deficient. Try entering 2 or more  characters for `char: `.

Comment: for my problem, i will only read a single character for char, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You never declared a variable named `Lista`.